# Cordova 6.0.0 No Network

Tags: android, cordova, networking, sencha-touch

I recently created a Cordova app using version 6.0.0 and cannot get networking to work. My config.xml looks like this:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

I know that's not recommended but for testing I would think this would be as permissive as possible but I am still not able to make requests to the network.

I've verified no network access both because my code notifies me when the app boots, as well as by issuing requests through the chrome debug console at chrome:inspect to various urls that work in my desktop browser.

Has anyone else run into this with Cordova 6.0.0 or any other version?

Thanks in advance for any help, I hope this is a simple misunderstanding of how Cordova handles networking permissions.

bwags

EDIT: Thanks jcarrera for pointing me towards the Content-Security-Policy meta tag. I was able to get everything working by adding Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only which leads me to believe this is almost certainly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Internet permission into your AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and also adding this meta tag into your html file(s):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="*" />
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I already had the AndroidManifest INTERNET permission, and the CSP tag (minus content="*") in the index file. Adding the content="*" unfortunately did not help. Thank you though :-/

Comment: content="" without the asterisk?

Comment: Sorry, the asterisk is there..just didn't make it's way into the comment. I copy pasted....must have gotten formatted out.

I am making ground though working on the Content-Security-Policy...I'm pretty sure you were correct in suspecting something up there

Comment: lol...spent the last 30 min trying to get my Content-Security-Policy setup to allow all the scripts I need and when I finally got it setup I got the same result as with the empty Content-Security-Policy tag.